# How to calculate "Kronecker Product" of a vector and a matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to compute the following forumula:

Fromula in TeX:

```
$\sum_n^N \sum_m^N a_n * a_m * C_{nm}$
```

Peudocode:

```py
a = array of length N
C = NxN matrix
retval = 0
for n in range(N):
    for m in range(N):
         retval += a[n] * a[m] * C[n][m]
```

If `a` were a NxN matrix constructed as in the product above one could simply use `np.kron` for the Kronecker Matrix multiplication and then use `np.sum` to get the desired result. However I don't know a faster numpy way of constructing a matrix A as in the formula above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could directly use those iterators for [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) string-notation -

```
retval = np.einsum('n,m,nm->',a,a,C)
```

Alternatively, with [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
retval = a.dot(C).dot(a)
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer. Do you know which of the two is faster? Probably `np.dot` right?

Comment: @jaaq Think it would depend on the array sizes. Can you test out on your use-case?

Comment: Times are: `Naive for loops: 6m35s` `dot method: 4m10s` `einsum: 4m4s`